# C# Future implementation with time out detection

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, future

I have a scenario where I need to split off a thread for work. If I get a result that's bad but my code will continue along fine. I really need to know if the processing exceeded my predetermined timeout. I have a Future implementation that looks a lot like . I am bound to .NET 3.5 so I don't have the ability to use what was introduced in 4.0 that seem to make it easy work.

I have a Future implementation that looks a lot like:

```
public class Future<T> {
        public delegate R FutureDelegate<R>();
        public Future (FutureDelegate<T> del) {
                Del = del;
                Result = del.BeginInvoke(null,null);
        }
        private FutureDelegate<T> Del;
        private IAsyncResult Result;
        private T PValue;
        private bool HasValue = false;
        private T Value {
                get {
                        if (!HasValue) {
                                if (!Result.IsCompleted)
                                        Result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                                PValue = Del.EndInvoke(Result);
                                HasValue = true;
                        }
                        return PValue;
                }
        }
        public static implicit operator T(Future<T> f) {
                return f.Value;
        }
}
```

I didn't write this code but it appears to be from a [blog](http://porg.es/blog/implementing-futures-in-c) I've found while trying to solve this issue. First instincts were to add a boolean `TimedOut` flag I could could check after WaitOne like:

```
            if (!Result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout_ms))
            {
                HasTimedOut = true;
                HasValue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                HasTimedOut = false;
                HasValue = true;
            }
```

However, I wrote a test checking this and it appears to always fail in the case of a timeout...always returning HasTimedOut as false. It should be return true if I make the test case:

```
var aFuture = new Future<int>(delegate {Sleep(5)l return 1+1;}, 1);
Assert.IsTrue(aFuture.HasTimedOut);
```

This is of course unless I'm making a leap of assumptions here. Do I have a misunderstanding? What would be the best way to get this feedback for a client class? I also tried throwing an exception but I presumably was just killing the current flow of control and not getting anything meaningful back to the client code.

Comment: Any feedback on whether my test is flawed or the means of detecting a timeout is totally welcome and appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving some of the implementation details around allowed me to achieve the desired result. See below:

```
    public Future(FutureDelegate<T> del, int timeout_ms)
    {
        Del = del;
        Result = del.BeginInvoke(null, null);

        if (!Result.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (!Result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout_ms))
            {
                HasTimedOut = true;
            }
            else
            {
                HasTimedOut = false;
            }
        }

        PValue = Del.EndInvoke(Result);             
    }
```

Pushing the code into the constructor allowed either throwing an exception or setting the HasTimedOut flag and persist it until I needed it.